# apply a calculation for each unique value in a column with filters in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

There could be an easier way to do this but I am struggling to find the right language to search for a solution so I decided to just post it.

I am essentially trying to create a new column where for each value in column A, we filter two other columns and apply a calculation.

My data looks like this:

```
user_loc fr_loc distance country_1990_user country_1990_fr ew_border_user ew_border_fr
  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>             <chr>                    <dbl>        <dbl>
1 DE11     DE12       77.2 DE                DE                           0            0
2 DE11     DE13      137.  DE                DE                           0            0
3 DE11     DE14       88.2 DE                DE                           0            0
...
10 DE12     DED2      190.  DE                GC                           0            0
11 DE12     DED4      249.  DE                GC                           0            1
12 DE11     DE23      206.  DE                DE                           0            0
```

user_loc and fr_loc are each NUTS2 regions in Germany. Distance is the distance between their centroids, country_1990_user and country_1990_fr is whether they were part of east or west germany in 1990 (DE is West Germany, GC is East). I've calculated a border dummy for the user and fr. which basically just describes whether they were along the east-west border or not.

What I want to do is:
for each unique value in user_loc, filter for values where country_1990 are different (GC and DE pairs only), and filter for ew_border_fr==1, and calculate the minimum distance. In other words, the closest NUTS2 region that is in the other country and touches the border for each user_loc.

I have tried this:

```
nuts2_dist_germ2 <- nuts2_dist_germ %>%
  group_by(user_loc) %>%
  filter(country_1990_user != country_1990_fr) %>%
  filter(ew_border_fr == 1) %>%
  mutate(min_border_dist = min(distance))
```

which does mostly get what I want but it ends up deleting about 100 observations and I don't understand why. I also tried doing this in a for loop fashion (which is not my strong suit) but this ended up just giving me the overall minimum distance. This was my code for that:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(nuts2_dist_germ)) {
  nuts2_dist_germ %>%
    group_by(user_loc) %>%
  filter(country_1990_user != country_1990_fr) %>%
    filter(ew_border_fr == 1) %>%
    mutate(min_border_dist = min(distance))

}
```

Does anyone have a better way to give me what I want? I essentially want a repeated distance that is the minimum for each user_loc. The former code did give me that but is dropping observations and I don't understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: Which observations is it dropping that it should not?  Only 1 in the sample has mismatched countries and ew_border_fr == 1. Could you include some sample rows it deletes in error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is dropping observations because that's what `dplyr::filter()` does.

I would create the new variable first but using an `if_else()` call to only calculate it in the conditions of interest, and then `summarise()`:

```r
dat |> 
  mutate(
    distance2 = if_else(
      country_1990_user != country_1990_fr & ew_border_fr == 1,
      true = distance,
      false = NA_real_
    )) |>
  group_by(user_loc) |>
  summarise(min_distance = min(distance2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output

```r
  user_loc min_distance
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 DE11              Inf
2 DE12              249
```